# Have an intermittent fault with my website- Err connection time out

Tags: web-development, timeout

Would be greatly appreciated if I can use some help here.

We have created a website and the problem we're facing is that we intermittently gets the below seen page:

[image]

Initially, I thought it was because my website was too slow to load and I have optimised it already. However, it doesn't seem to solve the problem.

Also, whenever we see the above page, probably about 4-5 secs later, the error code will disappear and my website will load up really really slowly. Anyone can advise me how to solve the problem? I'm quite sure is something to do with the website because only my website is facing this problem so far.

Comment: The error is near instant (I got a "this site could not be reached" error but then the site did load after some seconds) - this perhaps suggests a problem with the DNS?

Comment: Individual website troubleshooting is considered off-topic here. You only have a [single DNS](http://network-tools.com/default.asp?prog=dnsrec&host=www.yeobuild.com.sg) record (an `A` record) for `www`, and traceroutes are timing out.. Please contact your provider (ipage.com) for help.

Comment: This is not necessarily a web site problem. This is generally a network error.